# how to create a folder in wordpress

Tags: directory

This is the dilema:
I want to install wordpress in the root (regular installation for a wordpress site). Although, I want to have different cities to be available for the user to view the content depending on their choice.

Example:
1. I have 2 cities (New York and Miami)
2. User chooses Miami
3. URL path should be: http://www.domain.com/miami/
4. All information about Miami should be displayed (nothing about New York)

When creating pages or post ( I would like to have the choice as an admin to put it on the folder(city) I choose to.

Hope I am clear on my dilema.
Thank you.

Comment: How to create folder on WordPress website

Answer (score 5):

It might be best not to think of it as "folders" since it all runs off of index.php. The rest of the URL structure does not represent the file structure (eg Folders) but the permalink rewriting structure. (And thus make sure you have Permalinks enabled.)

To create example.com/miami, you would create a Page within WordPress and set its URL to miami. You can then create "child pages" by creating a page, and selecting Miami as its "parent" page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Organizing_Your_Pages

Comment: This is correct. Thinking with the 'folders' mindset will get you all sorts of confused in WordPress. You're better off following the above advice, since you have so much control over how you want the URL to look like in the end. The only time you should continue using the 'folders' mindset is when you're building/modifying a theme - and even then it's really only for organization's sake.